# "Back to top" in sticky social bar (for mobile)?

Tags: usability, back-button, social

i read more about "back to top" button and i understand that maybe i should to use it only for mobile (because for desktop is easy to got at top- start of the page with mouse, while with mobile is not easy). The problem that in my mobile website will be "sticky menu" and also sticky social bar (fixed on the bottom edge and so not in vertical position on right or left side). 
In a page with more elements i want to put the button in the share bar (maybe that fadein only when i scroll the page).. So to have a bar with only best social media (for example twitter, facebook, google+ and maybe also whatsapp) and a white space for the button...

What do you think ?
In a rich page i not want that the button is out and hidden other text of the page...

Is there another way?

Sorry for my english...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the initial purpose of the back to the top button was to help users reach the top easily, specifically when they didn't have a sticky nav for a mobile view.

I recommend not including a back to the top button if you have a sticky nav bar that is easily accessible.

Comment: It says it might be helpful to go to the top of the content (the title, for example, or to read the first rows)?

And in the desktop version where I have not the sticky menu and sticky social bar, the user might need the BTT?

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not users would receive benefit from a back-to-top (BTT) button/link/icon is dependent on a few things. First, how much content is your average page going to have?  If it's only a few paragraphs and users will only ever have to scroll half a page, a BTT button is probably overkill.  Likewise, if you have a sticky header; therefore, the only reason someone would go back to the top is to reread part of the content, a BTT button is also not very useful.

In order for a BTT button to be useful, you'll probably need to satisfy a couple constraints:

- you need enough content where users will actually scroll a decent amount
- there needs to be a reason why users would want to jump to the top
- manually going to the top of the page would introduce a noticeable delay

If you do decide on having a BTT button, there's a couple things you could do to ensure it doesn't get in the way:

- only show it once the use has scrolled down a certain amount on the page
- use the `opacity` style attribute so even when it is visible, it's not blocking content
- likewise, you could use the `:hover` selector to change the `opacity` to 1

Overall, from the information given, I don't believe your users would benefit from a BTT button, but ultimately you know your content best, and even if it doesn't add much value, as long as you implement it correctly, it should hurt the value either way.

Comment: Your ask is good, but i would like if you ask me also at other small questions that i made.. (See the other comment). Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If there is lot of scrolling involved then you would need a BTT button.

From what you say you can have one in the sticky menu, but make it visible only after scrolling

i would recommend that this button be visible just above the sticky menu on the right side (not too close to the right border) and be visible only after scrolling

Comment: Why do you say that should be above the sticky menu?

The menu bar and the social (being sticky) still reduce the reading area, and although the BTT is opaque and appears only when you scroll, however, is a distraction. Because in my social bar there will be space advancing, I wanted to put the BTT in this space (on the right side of the social bar). What do you say?

Comment: From my perspective i wanted to differentiate page actions from global actions. also users might not expect to see it after the social icons

However if space is an major constraint then i am fine to put iton the right side of the social bar

Answer (score 0):

Hide the back to top until they are scrolled about two screens worth. Only show it when scrolling and set a 1.5s delay for it to then fadeout. This way users will see it when they need it (scrolling) and it won't be in the way when they are trying to consume content.